# Can you manually set Tensorflow LSTM weights?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'm exploring using recurrent neural networks to work on unsupervised problems. I would need to set the weights for each gate individually. Is there any way I can do so? Is there anything like this?

```
LSTMCell.Weights['Forget'] = ForgetGateWeights
```

Comment: In inplementation, four weight tensors are concated to a bigger one, so if you want to pass a specific value to it, you have to do the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question was raised in the issues section in tensorflow. Checkout this discussion https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3115.

Comment: according to that, it seems that to assign weights, i should use assign. what do i assign them to?

Comment: As discussed in the article, you can't explicitly specify the weight of any particular gate. Though it is possible to specify weight matrix which is shared by all the gates. An alternative is to implement your own cell for greater control over parameters. Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318812/tensorflow-rnn-weight-matrices-initialization

Comment: Alright, i think I'll do that second approach. Thanks! :)