# Freezing an LSTM layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

Is it possible to freeze one LSTM layer and build another LSTM layer on the top of it?

The idea is quite simple but mechanism in Tensorflow makes it harder. All I need to do is to build one LSTM layer and save the model.  Then, I restore this model to get kernel (weight) matrix and biases using:

`tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/LSTM_cell/kernel:0") tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/LSTM_cell/bias:0")`

Then, I want to get these two tensors and keep them untrained and build another LSTM layer on the top of this then fetch the variables of the second layer.

However, the only topic I came up related to what I want to do is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962281/can-you-manually-set-tensorflow-lstm-weights) and it says that it is not possible, because I cannot set weights manually.

Doing this is super simple in feed forward neural network.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: did 'tf.stop_gradient()' not work?

Comment: `tf.stop_gradient` will work for cases when we do not want to optimize the loss function with respect to some variables during back-propagation. What I want is to set manually kernel and biases of an LSTM layer (that I got from a parallel iteration) and build another new LSTM layer on the top of it, while keeping the weight and bias matrices of the first layer untrained.

Comment: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm you can write weight and bias initiliazer functions and with these functions you can return the weights and biases of another LSTM layer. give the custom initiliazers to your LSTM layer, `LSTM(out_dim , kernel_initializer= my_kernel_init , recurrent_initializer=my_reccurrent_init)`.  Page about initiliazers : https://keras.io/initializers/


You can get the weights of another layer with . `get_weights()` , and `.trainable_weights`

Comment: I am using Tensorflow not Keras but that gave me an excellent idea! Thank you very much, Mete Han!