# Clockwork RNN (CW-RNN) and TanH activation function

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

Thanks again for taking the time to answer this post !

Quick question : 
In a *Clockwork Reccurent Neural Network* (RNN), ([here](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/koutnik14.pdf) is the documentation),
 it seems to me that a **TanH-activated output layer** would suffer from extreme load from so many connections, and alway output near **1** , or am I mistaken ?

Let's say we have a *CW-RNN* with, for the hidden layer, **4** modules of **50** neurons each.

Even if these modules have a different clock rate, obviously sometimes, more than 1 module will activate & output something else that 0 : Thus, the **output layer** *may* output **1** because of so many inputs.

Is there anything I am missing in the CW-RNN concept ?
I know about [weight initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318812/tensorflow-rnn-weight-matrices-initialization), but i'm just wondering if I am missing a piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CW-RNN, but how is the TANH more susceptible to 'extreme load' than other activation functions? like SIGMOID?
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function. Additionally, through backpropagation the weights will become less and less if that 'extreme load' forms a barrier to your problem. And last: don't forget bias!

Comment: Thanks for you comment ! You're right, Tanh/Sigmoid are both susceptible to this problem . However , what if there are so many inputs that event the first forward pass doesnt go through ? (First foward pass Ouput =1 ,Therefore, cannot backpropagate). Is the weights initialization the only option to counter this behavior ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why `output=1` can't backpropagate. But i'm not familiar with CW-RNN's, sorry!